# Is it right to say "Smokers should be got rid of"?

Tags: passive-voice

I know that sentences like "It is done", "She could be heard" are right, because it conforms to passive voice rules. So, I have compared "Smokers should be got rid of" with such examples. It seems to me to be right, because here I have used past participle form of the verb "get", but I am not sure if I have put the last preposition in right place. On the whole, it appears to me to be weird. Is this sentence correct at all?

Comment: Well  it's okay, but what do you mean by 'got rid of'? It's not the most natural thing to say. And when you 'get rid of' a person or a thing you usually throw it away or eliminate them somehow.

Comment: Negative externalities associated with smokers should be eliminated.

Comment: 'Faulty electric blankets should be got rid of' is a less contentious example; it's fine in an informal register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly good. Some would not approve of it in writing, mostly because of the colloquial phrase "get rid of".

[A few dinosaurs still object to the preposition at the end, but that so-called rule was nonsense when it was invented, and is now mostly recognised as nonsense].

Comment: *Be gotten rid of* is nearly as common as *be got rid of* in American English these days.

Comment: @Yoqubjon Jo'rayev I don't mean to challenge that fine progressive thinking; but why stand by this phrase "should be got rid of"? Isn't it at least distracting? A simple passive verb -- Smokers should be exiled, or banished, or killed, or forbidden, or barred or expelled or something -- would be a step in the right direction; and an even simpler active voice -- We should forbid smokers, we should slaughter smokers, etc. -- would be even better. No?

Comment: @Chaim: better by what criteria? Of your "exiled, or banished " etc, some are inappropriate, and some are needlessly specific. If the writer wanted the vagueness of "got rid of", what is wrong with that? And again, of course it could be put in the active, but in what way would that be "better"?

Comment: We are in no position to judge the propriety or needed specificity, since the example has no context. Of course I was trying to be funny in offering such persuasive methods, but each of those words is appropriate to some context, and Yoqubjon knows the facts better than you and I. Sometimes specificity is good. But do you think that an active construction (We should get rid of smokers.) is as likely to distract Yoqubjon and all other sensitive readers as the original one (Smokers should be got rid of.)? I don't think it is.

Comment: I totally disagree with you, and believe there was every good reason for a rule which proscribed prepositional endings. They are the fag ends of language. ***Of smokers, we (the world) should be rid***. (No pun intended).

Comment: As a answer to Chaim. I know, there are a variety of ways to express such a meaning. But when I was writing an essay, I wanted to write a sentence with a very unique approach, and chose exactly this phrase "to get rid of", (one more uniqueness here is that it has a preposition in the end) because it would appear kind of challenging to determine whether it is right or wrong, so I was curious to know it, from the perspective of native speakers.